# Regular expression performance issue on Android

Tags: android, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to make an app where you type the order you want the mobile to perform and the mobile recognizes orders using patterns and reqularExpressions.

But I have a real performance issue in this exact regular expression, as it takes too much time to process and usually it freezes my UI and force stops the app. This is the expression:

```
Send(\s*[a-z]*\s*)*message(\s*[A-Z]*[a-z]*\s*)*
```

Comment: What input strings are being checked by it, where it's taking too long?

Comment: `(`...`*`...`*)*` if possible [avoid such constructs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) that can [explode](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html) ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/VThKIv/1)) maybe [some simple regex similar to this](https://regex101.com/r/VThKIv/2) would be sufficient for your input.

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks man that really helped :))))

Comment: You're welcome @AliMSafi!

Answer (score 0):

`(`...`*`...`*)*` if possible [avoid such constructs](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) that can [explode](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-explosive-quantifiers.html) ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/VThKIv/1)) maybe [some simple regex similar to this](https://regex101.com/r/VThKIv/2) `Send[\sa-z]*message[\sa-zA-Z]*` would be sufficient for your input.
                    – bobble bubble